# calling an activity from a ListPrefernce

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity, listpreference

Hi I am developing an android SMS app where in I am trying to include settings.xml with preferences containing two CheckBoxPreference and a ListPreference similar to link

https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/09/creating-a-preference-activity-in-android/.

I want the ListPreference to show default ringtones from the phone.How do I call an activity from a listprefernce

```
public class Preference extends PreferenceActivity implements OnPreferenceClickListener 
{
   private ListPreference mListPreference;
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference);

       mListPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new  OnPreferenceChangeListener() 
       {
          public boolean onPreferenceChange(android.preference.Preference preference, Object newValue)
        {
          //how to call an activity in this place
          return true;
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, what you really want to have is a `RingtonePreference`:

```
<RingtonePreference android:key="ringtone" android:ringtoneType="notification"/>
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/RingtonePreference.html